# Google Maps javascript API, searchbox for directions to show on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a web project that gives directions from a set address(coordinates set in jscode) to an address that is set by the user using a text searchbox(in another div). I've managed to set the searchbox to give the address to a marker on the map, but I can't get the directions from "home" to the marker to work.

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
function initMap() {
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(60.124639, 19.948736);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('address'));

  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  

    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(15);  
    }
    marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
    });
  }

  setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
  setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
}

function codeAddress() {

  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(10);
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
      
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

    //<![CDATA[
 var pinColor1 = "FE7569";
 var pinColor2 = "0000FF";
    

    function load() {
           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: latlng,
    destination: geocoder.geocode,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}


map.mapTypes.set('map_style', custom_style);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load);
```

```css
html, body, .mapcontainer, #map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div>
        <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="SÖK ADRESS" id="address" onchange="calcRoute();"/>
</div>
<div class="mapcontainer col s12 m6 l6">
     <div class="col s6" id="map"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just try this Here the search box are googlemaps auto search box and it will show the direction between to points.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title> Directions</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var source, destination;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        debugger;
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
    });

    function GetRoute() {
        var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: mumbai,
            durationInTraffic: true
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

        //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
        source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

        var request = {
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

        //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status) {
            debugger;
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

            } else {
                alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        Source:
        <input type="text" id="txtSource" value="Bandra, Mumbai, India" style="width: 200px" />
        &nbsp; Destination:
        <input type="text" id="txtDestination" value="Andheri, Mumbai, India" style="width: 200px" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" />
        <hr />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div id="dvDistance">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```